# Why is entity framework getting called on a ASP.net page when it is not declared there?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have ASP.NET website. I have deliberately made the database offline so that I can check whether My Custom error pages are running fine & getting shown.

In my Error Page : I do not have any ASP.NET Entity framework used. It is an ASP.NET Page because I am using Resources for Localization. (& thus will not be able to convert to html page)

My Web.config says this :

```
 <system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" />
    <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="LargeFileError.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>
 </system.webServer>

 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">    
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error.aspx" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

In Application_Error of Global.asax.

```
  protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
             Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError(); 
           Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");     
        }
```

I keep on getting this error :

> "The underlying provider failed on Open."

The stack trace is :

> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean
>   shouldMonitorTransactions)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(WrappedEntityKey
>   key, String keyValuesParamName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[]
>   keyValues)    at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
>   at System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider.DoGet(HttpContext
>   context, String id, Boolean exclusive, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan&
>   lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions)    at
>   System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object&
>   lockId, SessionStateActions& actions)    at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()    at
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object
>   source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

You might say that there are lot of solutions on stack overflow for this error. I have gone through them & they are not helpful for me as In that Error page I do not have entity framework (My website pages do have it) at all & I am expecting this error to come.

Even when I am going Navigating to error.aspx page, I am getting this error. This page has no reference to asp.net entity framework.

How do I solve this & ensure that my error pages are getting shown if database is offline.

Comment: What makes you think this is Entity Framework? Do you have any custom profile/membership code perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG Please check the edit. My website uses entity framework but the custom error page does not.

Comment: So you are storing session state in your database perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG yes. that is a different database & it is online.

Comment: The error message doesn't suggest it is online...

Comment: @DavidG Yes you are correct. Some team member changed the session database to point to same database. However, I still want to see my custom error page .

Comment: Well, that's a different question.

Comment: Ok. Will ask a new question. Thanks

Comment: Are you running your solution in debug mode?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan No it is hosted on iis. I got the issue. just need to see how to mitigate session database offline

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed happy to know you found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was My sessions were being stored in database & hence the call from entity framework even in the error.aspx page.

To take it to error page I had to remove session state from the error page by using the directive `EnableSessionState="false"`.